# Asp.net core not using the correct certificate

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, https

I am trying to understand how certificates work with asp.net 5.0. I have created a self signed certificate using PKI Client and installed it to the certificate store trusted root.

I have updated my Kestrel config as below

```
"Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },

      "HttpsInlineCertStore": {
        "Url": "https://*:5001",
        "Certificate": {
          "Subject": "pal.com",
          "Store": "My",
          "Location": "LocalMachine",
          "AllowInvalid": "false" // Set to true to allow invalid certificates (e.g. self-signed)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

When I run my server and browse to path https://pal.com:5001/ it complains about the certificate. It looks like the browser is using the asp.net core development certificate

I am new to asp.net and ssl. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Hi @pal, try to investigate this [article](https://www.humankode.com/asp-net-core/develop-locally-with-https-self-signed-certificates-and-asp-net-core) and implement in your project. I think it will help you.

Comment: Did you check *with your browser* that it is indeed the development certificate that is being used here? Try changing the port to something else to verify that the configuration is picked up here.

Comment: @poke, yes the browser does seem to use the dev certificate. Interestingly when I changed my config settings to use HTTPS port other than 5001, it does not work. Server still uses 5001 as the HTTPS port, not sure where the server is getting the port from.

Comment: @DarkSideMoon, thanks for the link. Will have a read.

Comment: ok, I got this working. That was me doing things incorrectly, I added Kestrel config in launchSettings file rather than appsettings. It worked after moving the config to appsettings.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I got this working. That was me doing things incorrectly, I added Kestrel config in launchSettings file rather than appsettings. It worked after moving the config to appsettings.json file